# Should my blog be directly on my website?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, blog, pagerank, traffic

I have my newly launched website at `www.slicify.com` (redirects to a secure subdomain).

I currently have a separate blog on WordPress: `slicify.wordpress.com` for a couple of reasons:

- I don't really want to mix my site code (it's a complex ecommerce site written in ASP.Net) with blog code, for ease of maintenance etc.
- WordPress is already great at blogs - seems silly to reinvent the wheel by trying to integrate blog functionality into my site

However is keeping my blog on a separate domain going to hurt me in terms of PageRank or traffic?

FWIW: while it's early days, I can see from Google Analytics that a good deal of referral traffic is already coming from my WordPress site to my main site, so at least that seems to be drawing potential users in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a blog on another website won't hurt your PR or traffic (as long as you aren't duplicating content between the two).

However you could be missing out on any extra traffic to your site that the blog might bring if it was on your site. You will also benefit from the content being on your site SEO wise, as search engines like sites with lots of content on.

So it won't actually hurt you site having the blog hosted else where, but you could be missing out on many advantages.

I'm sure you could quite easily install a WordPress blog in a subfolder or subdomain of your site without having to integrate it into your current site. You dont even have to theme it to match your site, you can use a standard theme.

There is quite a lot of documentation available on installing WordPress on ISS, you might want to start here: [Installing Wordpress on Microsoft IIS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS).

Answer (score 1):

I add that having 2 domains, `www.slicify.com` and `slicify.wordpress.com`, could be confusing. Use a `blog.slicify.com` domain, it's the standard.